# Apps Script Error - Time Off Request Form

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm getting the error message below when trying to use a Time Off Request Form solution created by Google.

> TypeError: Cannot call method "match" of undefined. (line 287, file "Code")

line 287 is

```
manager_email = d[SETTINGS.MANAGERS_EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME].match(EMAIL_REGEX);
```

and the Regular Expression is defined previously as

```
var EMAIL_REGEX = new RegExp("[a-zA-Z+0-9\.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\.-]+", 'i');
```

if I delete the match method from line 287, so that it reads

```
manager_email = d[SETTINGS.MANAGERS_EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME]
```

I get the following error

> Invalid email: undefined (line 298, file "Code")

line 298 is

```
MailApp.sendEmail(manager_email,subject,"",{ htmlBody: message });
```

Can anyone suggest a fix?

Comment: That error means that property is not present in `d`.

Comment: Any suggestions for how I can fix it? I didn't write this code and am a novice. It was supposed to work as is after replacing a few identifiers (calendar and spreadsheet IDs)

Comment: The solution overview, including all 449 lines of code, is here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y6x90S_q_cwdl4LGVDDSqMyuikx1zmPFyVQfSlYsKLk/edit?usp=sharing